# shell script with "while" loop and numeric test does not work

Tags: linux, shell, unix, scripting

can someone help me spot the problem here ?

```
#!/bin/sh

find . -name '*ABC*' > replace_temp.file
num_of_lines=`cat replace_temp.file | wc -l`
i=0
while $i<$num_of_lines
do
   tc=`expr $i + 1`
   line=`tail -$tc replace_temp.file |head -1`
   line1=$line
   sed -e 's/\(.*\)ABC/\1DEF/' $line
   #mv -f $line1 $line   
done 
#rm -f replace_temp.file
```

i get the error `replace.sh: line 6: 20: No such file or directory`

purpose of this script: search and replace all files  directories containing `ABC` in their name to `DEF`

it goes through the lines of find results file from bottom to top so there wont be any problems with dir dependencies (eg changing name of one dir will mess up changing the name of it's sub dir)

thanks

Comment: another quick related question: how do i save the result of `sed -e 's/\(.*\)ABC/\1DEF/' $line` into a parameter rather than execute it ? i mean i want the sed command to be executed on `$line` parameter so the parameter itself is changed so i can use it later.

Comment: Why not just do `find . -depth -name '*ABC*' -print0 | xargs -0 rename 's/ABC$/DEF/'`?

Comment: @markwilliams i tried it. the problem is that my raname(1) on my distro does not support regex. i have this version of rename http://linux.die.net/man/1/rename

Comment: ...and what I wrote would only work if the file/directory **ended** with ABC.  Double whoops.  I suppose I'd do `find . -depth -name '*ABC*' -exec ./renamer.sh {} \;` where `./renamer.sh` consists of: `mv "$1" "$(echo "$1" | sed -e 's#\(.*/.*\)ABC\(.*\)#\1DEF\2#')"`

Comment: If you were a shell, how would you know `$i<$num_of_lines` is not a redirection for the command `$i` reading stdin from `$num_of_lines`? What kind of error does your shell report for `nosuchcommand < nosuchfile`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
while $i<$num_of_lines
```

should be something like

```
while [ $i -lt $num_of_lines ]
```

or if you insist

```
while (($i < $num_of_lines))
```

Comment: you're right, it fixed it. but now it goes on an infinite loop writing `sed: read error on ./admin-ABC: Is a directory`. do i have to increment the `$i` parameter or does it get incremented automatically ?

Comment: @michael `i` doesn't get incremented automatically

Answer (score 1):

It should be

```
while [ $i -lt $num_of_lines ]
  do

done
```

or

```
while (( $i -lt $num_of_lines ))
  do

done
```

or

```
while test $i -lt $num_of_lines
  do

done
```

You are running an infinite loop, you have never updated `$i` . Probably you would like to do something like `i=$((i+1))` inside the body of the loop, or update `$i` in any other way.

Comment: i see that,for some reason i thought it gets incremented automatically. thanks

Comment: @michael: is there any cause to think that $i gets incremented automagically ?

Answer (score 0):

Use `for tc in ((1..$num_of_lines)); do ... ; done`